# Rails 5.2 Partial Column with Background Image Rendering Differently Across Page

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three different places on a page where the same partial is being rendered.  The partial includes a bootstrap `col-sm-4`/`col-sm-8` situation that should make an image take up a third of the page and the text on the other 2/3.  However, in each instance the partial is rendering differently:

[image]

Here's the page (which is `blogs#index`):

```
<header class="py-5 bg-image-full bg-image-stripe" style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path "drops-of-water-mask.jpg" %>);">
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="display-4 mt-5 mb-2">The Blog</h1>
        <p class="lead mb-5">Your Source for Qualified Knowledge (or Other Tagline)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>


<% if current_spree_user && current_spree_user.admin? %>
  <section class="admin container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col text-left pt-3">
        <h2>Draft Posts</h2>
        <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
          <% if !blog.published %>
            <p class="my-1 py-0"><%= link_to blog.title, edit_blog_path(blog) %></p>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div> <!-- drafts col -->
      <div class="col text-right pt-3">
        <%= link_to "Create New Blog", new_blog_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <%= link_to "Blog Management", home_blogs_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div> <!-- create new col -->
    </div> <!-- row -->
  </section>

  <hr>
<% end %>


<main class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-12" id="big-feature">
      <% @big_feature.each do |blog| %>
        <%= render partial: "blogs/blog-card", locals: { blog: blog } %>
      <% end %> <!-- each do -->
    </div> <!-- col -->

    <div class="col-sm-6" id="most-popular">
      <h2>Most Popular</h2>
      <% @most_popular.each do |blog| %>
        <%= render partial: "blogs/blog-card", locals: { blog: blog } %>
      <% end %> <!-- each blog do -->
    </div> <!-- col -->

    <div class="col-sm-6" id="featured">
      <h2>Featured</h2>
      <% @featured.each do |blog| %>
        <%= render partial: "blogs/blog-card", locals: { blog: blog } %>
      <% end %> <!-- each blog do -->
    </div> <!-- col -->

  </div> <!-- row -->

</main> <!-- page container -->
```

And here's the `blogs/_blog-card` partial:

```
<%= link_to blog_path(blog) do %>
  <div class="blog-title-box my-3">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="image background-image col-md-4"
        style="background-image: url('<%= blog.featured_image_url %>')">
      </div> <!-- image col -->

      <div class="text col-sm-8 px-4 py-3">
        <h3><%= blog.title %></h3>
        <% if blog.big_feature %><p><%= blog.teaser %></p><% end %>
        <p class="tags"><% blog.tag_list.each do |tag| %>
          <%= link_to tag, tagged_path(tag: tag) %>
        <% end %></p>
        <p class="author"> By <%= Spree::User.find(blog.spree_user_id).email %> on <%= blog.published_at.in_time_zone("America/Los_Angeles").strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></p>
      </div> <!-- text col -->

    </div> <!-- row -->
  </div> <!-- blog title box -->
<% end %> <!-- link to blog -->
```

Here is any relevant CSS:

```
.blog-title-box {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(183, 173, 153, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(183, 173, 153, 0.23);
}

.blog-title-box:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(183, 173, 153, 0.30), 0 10px 10px rgba(183, 173, 153, 0.22);
}

.blog-title-box .image {
  height: 300px;
}

#big-feature a:hover,
#most-popular a:hover,
#featured a:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.blog-title-box .text p {
  color: black;
}

.blog-title-box .text p.author {
  color: $color-grey;
  font-style: oblique;
}

.background-image {
  background-position: center; /* Center the image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the image */
  background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Can anyone see why only the blog under "most popular" is rendering correctly?

**Additional Information**

Here's how the page renders in HTML, according to Chrome inspector:

```
<main class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-12" id="big-feature">
        <a href="/blogs/3">
  </a><div class="blog-title-box my-3"><a href="/blogs/3">
    </a><div class="row"><a href="/blogs/3">

      <div class="image background-image col-md-4" style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/water-with-splash-and-bubbles-picture-id952077910')">
      </div> <!-- image col -->

      </a><div class="text col-sm-8 px-4 py-3"><a href="/blogs/3">
        <h3>Test for Big Feature</h3>
        <p>Teaser Goes Here.  Yes, all the things.</p>
        </a><p class="tags"><a href="/blogs/3">
          </a><a href="/tagged?tag=Big+Post">Big Post</a>

          <a href="/tagged?tag=Testing">Testing</a>
        </p>
        <p class="author"> By lizbayardelle@gmail.com on September 26, 2019</p>
      </div> <!-- text col -->

    </div> <!-- row -->
  </div> <!-- blog title box -->
 <!-- link to blog -->

       <!-- each do -->
    </div> <!-- col -->

    <div class="col-sm-6" id="most-popular">
      <h2>Most Popular</h2>
        <a href="/blogs/2">
  <div class="blog-title-box my-3">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="image background-image col-md-4" style="background-image: url('https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/9ebfe6eb392f208e944a21d1903b698965d35527/0_0_7360_4417/master/7360.jpg?width=700&amp;quality=45&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;dpr=2&amp;s=2b05fd52feeac284411af1bf1215d1d6')">
      </div> <!-- image col -->

      <div class="text col-sm-8 px-4 py-3">
        <h3>Test Blog</h3>

        <p class="tags"></p>
        <p class="author"> By lizbayardelle@gmail.com on September 24, 2019</p>
      </div> <!-- text col -->

    </div> <!-- row -->
  </div> <!-- blog title box -->
</a> <!-- link to blog -->

       <!-- each blog do -->
    </div> <!-- col -->

    <div class="col-sm-6" id="featured">
      <h2>Featured</h2>
        <a href="/blogs/1">
  </a><div class="blog-title-box my-3"><a href="/blogs/1">
    </a><div class="row"><a href="/blogs/1">

      <div class="image background-image col-md-4" style="background-image: url('https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/9ebfe6eb392f208e944a21d1903b698965d35527/0_0_7360_4417/master/7360.jpg?width=700&amp;quality=45&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=max&amp;dpr=2&amp;s=2b05fd52feeac284411af1bf1215d1d6')">
      </div> <!-- image col -->

      </a><div class="text col-sm-8 px-4 py-3"><a href="/blogs/1">
        <h3>Yet Another Test Blog</h3>

        </a><p class="tags"><a href="/blogs/1">
          </a><a href="/tagged?tag=Fake+Content+Testing">Fake Content Testing</a>
        </p>
        <p class="author"> By lizbayardelle@gmail.com on September 25, 2019</p>
      </div> <!-- text col -->

    </div> <!-- row -->
  </div> <!-- blog title box -->
 <!-- link to blog -->

       <!-- each blog do -->
    </div> <!-- col -->

  </div> <!-- row -->

</main>
```

**EVEN MORE INFO**

You can see the [issue live here](https://laguna-greenworks-spree.herokuapp.com/blogs).

Comment: @Amessihel I added it to the OP.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Amessihel I added a link to the issue live.  There are too many libraries to use a snippet with any reliability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RoR code seems correct. You should end up with blog cards surrounded by **only one** anchor (`<a>` tag) like the sample below:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 pt-3" id="featured">
  <h2>Featured</h2>
  <!-- surrounding anchor ---------------------------------------------->
  <a href="/blogs/3"> 
    <div class="blog-title-box my-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="image background-image col-md-4"
           style="background-image: url('<the-url>')">
        </div>
        <div class="text col-sm-8 px-4 py-3">
          <h3>Test for Featured</h3>
          <p class="tags">
            <a href="/tagged?tag=Testing">Testing</a>
            <a href="/tagged?tag=Fake+Content">Fake Content</a>
          </p>
          <p class="author">
            By xxx@yyy.com on October 01, 2019
          </p>
        </div> 
      </div> 
    </div>
  </a>
  <!-- surrounding anchor (end) ----------------------------------------->
</div>
```

That sample correctly gets **correctly** the design you wish (1/3 for the image).

But the link you provided to the HTML result (issue live) shows duplicated anchors, some of them are empty:

```
<div class="blog-title-box my-3"><a href="/blogs/3"></a>
```

Other not. This one particularly **breaks the design**:

```
<div class="row">
  <a href="/blogs/3"> <!-- unexpected anchor breaking the design -->
    <div class="image background-image col-md-4"
         style="background-image: url('<the-url>')">
      <!-- [...] -->
    </div>
```

Since I cannot see the actual executed code, I can't go further than that. My guess is that you have to see in your RoR code what is inserting those annoying anchors. Are you sure the real executed code is the one you pasted in your question?

Comment: There wasn't an issue with more than one `<a>` tag at once, but any time there was one around the background image it displayed this malfunction.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of this appears to be that you have nested an anchor tag within another anchor tag.

> Can anyone see why only the blog under "most popular" is rendering correctly?

This one renders correctly because it has no links (anchor tags) in the descriptive text, unlike the other examples.

When you view the code of the broken layouts in the Chrome inspector it has moved the anchor tags to try and make since of the illegal code (nested anchor tags). But if you view the raw source code (view page source) you will see the original output of the RoR code.

Answer (score 0):

In the live example I am seeing the following code:

```
<div class="row">
  <a href="/blogs/1">
      <div class="image background-image col-md-4" style="background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/water-with-splash-and-bubbles-picture-id952077910')">
  </div> <!-- image col -->

  </a>

  <div class="text col-sm-8 px-4 py-3"><a href="/blogs/1">
    <h3>
      Sample Blog for Big Feature
    </h3>
    <p>Teaser Goes Here. Yes, all the things.</p>
    </a><p class="tags"><a href="/blogs/1">
        </a><a href="/tagged?tag=Testing">Testing</a>
        <a href="/tagged?tag=Big+Post">Big Post</a>
    </p>
    <p class="author">
      By lizbayardelle@gmail.com on October 01, 2019
    </p>
  </div> <!-- text col -->

</div>
```

The `div` with the background image is wrapped in an `a` tag and therefore the class `col-md-4` is fairly meaningless on the div. If you add the class `col-md-4` to the `a` tag it fixes the layout issue.

```
<a href="/blogs/1" class="col-md-4">
```

You could add the following css to get the same effect of the `col-md-4`:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .row > a {
        -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
        flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
        max-width: 33.333333%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your approach seems fine as it is valid to wrap a div with an anchor tag in html5. The code I have provided fixes the layout problem. If the anchor tag should not be there I can not help you with the RoR code sorry, that is not my area of expertise. All the best.

Comment: I believe I found the answer, due to nested anchor tags, and have posted it as a fresh answer.